# API 19 Scrollview no momentum

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-4.4-kitkat, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a NestedScrollView within a CoordinatorLayout and it contains a recyclerView. The whole fragment, which is very long, has no scroll momentum and I'm not sure what I can do to fix it. I previously had this problem with higher Android versions and was able to include

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

to solve my problem. However, that was added in api 21 and my project supports 19+. My app still has no momentum on this fragment for api 19 devices.

Below is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_margin_medium_huge"
                android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        <TypefaceTextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_title"
                android:layout_below="@id/logo"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/myStyle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TypefaceTextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_byline"
                android:text="@string/byline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/myStyle"
                android:layout_below="@id/textview_title"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>

        <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radiogroup_filter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@id/textview_byline"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <TypefaceRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_filter_new"
                    android:text="@string/filter_new"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/buttonStyleRadio"
                    android:theme="@style/ButtonSecondary"
                    android:button="@null"/>

            <TypefaceRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_filter_history"
                    android:text="@string/filter_history"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/ButtonStyleRadio"
                    android:theme="@style/ButtonSecondary"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:button="@null"/>

        </RadioGroup>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/radiogroup_filter"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_links"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/recyclerview"
                android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_link_1"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
                    app:layout_aspectRatio="158%"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
            <TypefaceTextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_link_1"
                    android:text="@string/text_1"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
                    app:layout_aspectRatio="158%"
                    android:gravity="bottom|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="32dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="32dp"
                    style="@style/myStyle"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_link_2"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
                    app:layout_aspectRatio="158%"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_below="@id/image_link_1"/>
            <TypefaceTextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_link_2"
                    android:text="@string/text_2"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
                    app:layout_aspectRatio="158%"
                    android:gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="32dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="32dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/image_link_1"
                    style="@style/myStyle"/>
        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Are you overriding the onTouch or onDispatchTouch in your application?

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira I am not :/

Comment: Try to update the support library in you grade file and your build tools

Comment: I created a test project with a similar layout, but so far the only way I can reproduce your symptoms is if I use images with large file sizes, in which case the scrolling effect is very poor.  Does your layout scroll smoothly, and it's only the fling effect that is not working?  What library are you using for the TypefaceTextViews? What sort of layout are you using for the items inside the RecyclerView?

Comment: Also, you have a PercentRelativeLayout nested inside another PercentRelativeLayout, but the outer one's direct children are not using the layout_widthPercent or layout_heightPercent attributes.  You may be able to flatten your view hierarchy by eliminating the outer PercentRelativeLayout.

Comment: @JasonPowell That's a helpful tip about the extra PercentRelativeLayout. I must have had it in earlier for a layout that had percentages and taken the inner layout out but forgot to change Percent back to normal RelativeLayout. As far as TypefaceTextview goes it's just a custom view that extends TextView for ease of coding. It might as well just be a TextView. The recyclerView contains cards that have an image background of moderate resolution. There are a lot of images on the screen when fully loaded. I get a choppy scroll where there is no momentum. i.e. when I let go, it stops immediately

Comment: Another interesting thing I just noticed is that if I scroll all the way to the bottom of the screen and then scroll up again, it has momentum again. All the way until it reaches the top portion of the screen, then it loses momentum again. Very strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to recreate your symptoms in my test project.  I fixed it be adding the following code in onCreate() for the activity:

```
final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(new RecyclerView.OnFlingListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        recyclerView.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, false);
        return false;
    }
});
```

I added a fling listener to the RecyclerView, and in onFling(), I call dispatchNestedFling() to let the parent know that a fling is occurring.  The parent can then consume the fling or observe the child fling.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html#dispatchNestedFling(float, float, boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html#dispatchNestedFling(float,%20float,%20boolean))

> dispatchNestedFling
>
> added in version 22.1.0
> boolean dispatchNestedFling (float velocityX,
> float velocityY,
> boolean consumed) Dispatch a fling to a nested scrolling parent.
>
> This method should be used to indicate that a nested scrolling child
> has detected suitable conditions for a fling. Generally this means
> that a touch scroll has ended with a velocity in the direction of
> scrolling that meets or exceeds the minimum fling velocity along a
> scrollable axis.
>
> If a nested scrolling child view would normally fling but it is at the
> edge of its own content, it can use this method to delegate the fling
> to its nested scrolling parent instead. The parent may optionally
> consume the fling or observe a child fling.

This is working on my emulator running API 19.  Obviously, YMMV.

Comment: Good!  Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 5):

There is a simpler way:

**Java**

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

**Kotlin**

```
recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```

Comment: Did you read the question? I tried that but it doesn't work for api 19... The accepted answer worked.

Comment: @kjanderson2 Dude, it's not working on XML, but it works when you set it in onCreate.