# RecyclerView inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

I try to implement a layout like below image.

in this layout first `ViewPager` has fix height and second `Viewpager` contain `RecyclerView`.

How can connect scroll `RecyclerView` in `Viewpager` to `NestedScrollView` in parent?

I try this:
`nestedScrollView.isFillViewport = true` but `RecyclerView` scroll from top of `Viewpager`.

[image]

Comment: You want Recycler View height to be wrap_content?

Comment: @Khemraj . i want `RecyclerView` scroll by `NestedScrollView`

Comment: Okay, you want `NestedScrolling` false, that will also make RecyclerView `wrap_content`. Complicated question, need to do some work.

Comment: People who don't understand question, they down-vote it. Weird!

Comment: @Khemraj . I really don't understand why get two negative vote

Comment: They are blind actually. It happens with me sometimes also.

Comment: It looks like NestedScrollView needs to have only one element inside of it.
So you could use LinearLayout inside of NestedScrollView to wrap all things inside it by its turn. Take a look if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced this issue some time ago. Where you want `RecyclerView` to be Scrolled by `NestedScrollView`. And `nestedScrollingEnabled` will not help you because `RecyclerView` is inside `ViewPager.`

**Solution** You can customize the `ViewPager` to resize the `ViewPager` to it's current page size on page swipe from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484833/viewpager-wrap-content-not-working/34524240#34524240).

You can use the following code:

```
 public class WrapContentViewPager extends ViewPager {

        private int mCurrentPagePosition = 0;

        public WrapContentViewPager(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public WrapContentViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        try {
             boolean wrapHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
             if (wrapHeight) {
                 View child = getChildAt(mCurrentPagePosition);
                 if (child != null) {
                 child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                 int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();

                 heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                }
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

        public void reMeasureCurrentPage(int position) {
            mCurrentPagePosition = position;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

Declare it in xml:

```
    <your.package.name.WrapContentViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </your.package.name.WrapContentViewPager>
```

After that call `reMeasureCurrentpage` function on page swipe.

```
    final WrapContentViewPager wrapContentViewPager = (WrapContentViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    wrapContentViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    wrapContentViewPager.reMeasureCurrentPage(wrapContentViewPager.getCurrentItem());
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
```

Also set `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. but in my application min sdk is 19 and `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false` require 21

Comment: Just place this in xml android:nestedScrollingEnabled, and try below 19 api with above answer.

Comment: Which case are you reffering

Comment: When `isFillViewport` set `false` for `NestedScrollView` `Viewpager` doesn't  show `RecyclerView` and with set  `isFillViewport=true` `RecyclerView` not scroll at all.

Comment: I did not mention to use `isFillViewport` in my answer.

Comment: Did you try using `WrapContentViewPager`

Comment: set `wrap_content` for `height` custom `ViewPager` but `RecyclerView` don't display

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177011/discussion-between-khemraj-and-saman).

Answer (score 1):

Set these line on your RecyclerView in XML

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
android:height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: In my case min sdk is 19

Comment: Then this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287798/api-19-scrollview-no-momentum#43333754 can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: layout]

Make your layout like this will work