# Swipe features in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

If I swipe left to right or right to left, then I swipe up or down without releasing finger  swiping up or down occurred on Scroll Gesture. But I don't want to occur this. I want if am swiping horizontally only horizontal swiping should work not vertical without release finger. I don't know how doing that in android studio, If anyone can help, please help me, thanks in advance.

I have already tried, but can't solve the above problem.

override fun onScroll(event: MotionEvent?, event1: MotionEvent?, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {

```
    val sWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val sHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels

    val border = 100 * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density.toInt()
    if(event!!.x < border || event.y < border || event.x > sWidth - border || event.y > sHeight - border)
        return false

    if(abs(distanceX) < abs(distanceY)){
        if(event.x < sWidth/2){
            //brightness
            // left side up and down
        }
        else{
            //volume
            // right side up and down
        
    }if (distanceY > distanceX){

       If (distance Y > 0){
            // left to right swipe
      }else{
        // right to left swipe
        }
   }

    return true
}
```

When I swipe up and down. Left or Right swipe also occur.

Comment: You need to give a lot more information about what types of views and touch or gesture recognizers are involved.  As is its impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer for a question related to a RecyclerView in a ViewPager. This problem might be similar to yours.

[Link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69572865/9612643)

The answer gives priority to the view which you want to scroll and nothing else!